# What can I know about this part of code?

Tags: shell, sed

What does this part of a script do?
This is a part of a scrpt in bash

```
for j in *.* ; do 
    cp $j ../../$name-S$i.gid/data/${j%%.*}$i.${j#*.}
    sed "s/$name-S/$name-S$i/" $j > ../../$name-S$i.gid/data/${j%%.*}$i.${j#*.}
done
```

I forgot to say that "i", is a parameter that goes from 1 to specific number and "$name" is a part of name of a folder.

Comment: Refer to _Shell Parameter Expansion_ in your shell reference manual.

Comment: What language is that written in, can we assume bash? Also we don't know what it does because you left out the part that defines `$i`. Not to mention `$name`.

Answer (score 1):

This is stupid code. First I rewrite it so that this becomes obvious (I add quoting, too):

```
for j in *.* ; do 
    target_file="../../$name-S$i.gid/data/${j%%.*}$i.${j#*.}"
    cp "$j" "$target_file"
    sed "s/$name-S/$name-S$i/" "$j" >"$target_file"
done
```

I.e. a file is copied and immediately afterwards the new file is overwritten. This is done for all files whose name contains a dot (but probably not at the beginning; depends (in `bash`) on the setting of `dotglob`).

The target file path is constructed as:

1. Put it in another directory.
2. Erase the file extension (all parts of it, i.e. everything from the first dot).
3. Add the number `i` and then the old extension.

The `sed` call replaces only the first (intentional limitation?) occurrance of `$name-S` (i.e. its expansion) in a line by `$name-S$i` (its expansion again).